# Hide android bottom buttons react native using expo build

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have a problem, that I want to hide bottom buttons on android system in my app. I use expo build for my app. Tried other solutions that I saw on stackoverflow, but it didn't worked. I installed libraries "react-native-immersive" and "react-native-immersive-mode" and got an error.
[expo error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6t3i.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

The Expo configuration file `app.json` at the root of your project it is possible to control the way the bottom bar of Android behaves with the `"androidNavigationBar"` property.

app.json

```json
{
  "androidNavigationBar": {
    "visible": "immersive",
  }
}
```

You can review the documentation following the following link: [Configuration with app.json - Expo Documentation](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/?redirected#androidnavigationbar)

Expo documentation is very well done and it will be easy for you to get information to do things correctly, greetings.

Comment: It works at start, but after showing up I don't know how to hide it back. Can you help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Right now expo makes it easy to configure this inside your app. it is possible to control this in any of your **views.js** . Check out the documentation here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/navigation-bar
example;

```
import * as NavigationBar from "expo-navigation-bar";

...
const [barVisibility, setBarVisibility] = useState();



NavigationBar.addVisibilityListener(({ visibility }) => {
    if (visibility === "visible") {
      setBarVisibility(visibility);
    }
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    navigationConfig();
  }, [barVisibility]);

  const navigationConfig = async () => {
    // Just incase it is not hidden
    NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync('red');

    // Hide it
    NavigationBar.setVisibilityAsync("hidden");
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

To everyone who may get this same problem. Edit your app.json with `androidNavigationBar` beneath the `expo`, like this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "androidNavigationBar": {
      "visible": "sticky-immersive"
    },
    ...
}
```

You have 3 options to the `visible` clause:

- `leanback` results in the navigation bar being hidden until the first touch gesture is registered.
- `immersive` results in the navigation bar being hidden until the user swipes up from the edge where the navigation bar is hidden.
- `sticky-immersive` is identical to 'immersive' except that the navigation bar will be semi-transparent and will be hidden again after a short period of time.

The package `expo-navigation-bar` is needed

```
npm install expo-navigation-bar
```

or

```
yarn add expo-navigation-bar
```

For more details read the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#androidnavigationbar)!